# Reduce Font Size of datatable in a Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard, htmlwidgets

I'm working on a shiny flexdashboard, and one of the elements is a datatable with a lot of columns. Currently the columns are so many that they exceed the width of the app.

Instead of adding a scroll bar I would prefer to simply reduce the font used in datatable so that each column will be smaller.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Needed to wrap renderDataTable in a div.

```
div(renderDataTable(table()),style = "font-size:80%)
```